# Splitting huge ngons

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

(Can't post images for some reason. Sorry.)

Combining two meshes resulted in huge ngons. I know I need to split the ngons, but I don't know the correct method for splitting them without creating artifacts when the subdivision surfaces modifier is applied. How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Making faces inside them quads with proper edge flow. Without images or blend file I can't tell you more.

Comment: There is no "correct way", you should be concerned with your overall mesh topology instead. This may help http://topologyguides.com